# drain array values in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Array

```
var array = [
    {
        item: "abcd1234",
        data: "something"
    },
    {
        item: "4321dcba",
        data: "something"
    },
];
```

Array length can be randomly from 1 to 10

I'm making http request for all these items.

```
array.forEach(function(item) {

    var url = "www.something.com?id=" + item.item;

    //making request

});
```

Now I need 1 - 10 requests per array depends on a array length.

Lets say I have 10 arrays with 10 elements in it. Its 100 requests.

I could do this with only 1 request per array if I use url like this

`www.something.com?id=abcd1234&id2=4321dcba`

How do I loop all array values to the url if I don't know how many elements there is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```js
const array = [
  {
    item: "abcd1234",
    data: "something"
  },
  {
    item: "4321dcba",
    data: "something"
  }
];
const url = array.reduce(
  (acc, x, i) => acc + (i === 0 ? `?id=${x.item}` : `&id${i + 1}=${x.item}`),
  'www.something.com'
);
console.log(url);
```

If your array looks like `["abcd1234", "4321dcba"]`, try this:

```js
const array = ['abcd1234', '4321dcba'];
const url = array.reduce(
  (acc, x, i) => acc + (i === 0 ? `?id=${x}` : `&id${i + 1}=${x}`),
  'www.something.com'
);
console.log(url);
```

Comment: perfect. What if I have array like this? `var array = ["abcd1234", "4321dcba"];`

Answer (score 2):

Use array-style URL parameter names. Most server-side libraries and frameworks will collect these into an array (e.g. `$_GET['id']` will be an array in PHP).

You can use `.map()` to return an array of all the parameters, and `.join()` to connect them with `&`.

```js
var array = [{
    item: "abcd1234",
    data: "something"
  },
  {
    item: "4321dcba",
    data: "something"
  },
];

var url = 'www.something.com?' +
  array.map(function(item) {
    return 'id[]=' + encodeURIComponent(item.item);
  }).join('&');

console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "www.something.com?"+items.map((item,id)=>"id"+((id||-1)+1)+"="+item.item).join("&");
```

You can map each item to its query parameter, and then join with the &...